# how to create module inside module in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have implemented HMVC for creating modules in codeigniter . Now I want to create modules inside module but unfortunately I am getting 404 page.

My current directory structure

modules/api/v1

when I am putting controller inside api/controller folder then it's working fine but when I put a controller file under api/v1/controller folder then it showing me 404 error. I want this because after implementing this all the version of my api will be inside a single folder

Please give me your suggestion how can I do This

Comment: try modules/api/controllers/v1/ (which version do you use ? )

Comment: @sintakonte How can I add controllers before v1 because v1 is a directory  inside api folder

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835155/create-modules-inside-a-module-in-codeigniter answers your question

Comment: @Shyamali I didn't understand how they are doing this I have made the changes according to them but still I am getting 404 page

Comment: Old tutorial series but a good one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fy8E_C5_qQ